# Create an XML file via an Eclipse RCP

Tags: xml, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I want to be able to create an XML file via an Eclipse RCP just like in Eclipse (`File > New > Other > XML > XML File`). The problem that I have is this : I don't have the XML folder in the  window that opened when I click **other**. Is there an easy way to add the XML folder in that window ?

Comment: Sorry, but your question is not clear enough to answer.  What do you mean by _"dont have the xml folder in the window that opened when I click other"_? What is "the xml folder"?

Comment: I mean in the wizard window, I dont have the xml folder. Maybe an image is better. http://imgur.com/hwB3aMf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new XML file page of the `New` wizard is provided by the XML component of Eclipse WST. So you are going to have to include at least part of the WST code in your RCP to get this.

Comment: How can I proceed to include WST in my RCP ? Is there a tutorial for this purpose ? Im asking you this question because Im really new to RCP development.

Comment: It is just a matter of including the WST plugins in the list of plugins used by your RCP (assuming your RCP is based on the standard Eclipse RCP).

Comment: Thanks greg-449.I just install all WTP plugins into the RCP eclipse target platform. Do i need to do something else in order to include the WST to my RCP ?

Comment: You just need to list the plugins (or features) in the `product` file you use to build the RCP.